# How to pack a character and a number correctly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, int, iterable, pack

I'm learning about client-server communication in python, and I want to send some packed structures.I want to pack a mathematical sign and a number. I tried like this:

```py
idx         = 50    
value1      = "<"
value2      = idx
packer      = struct.Struct('1s I')
packed_data = packer.pack(*value1, *value2)
```

But I got the error:

```
packed_data = packer.pack(*value1, *value2)
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

or this error:

```
packed_data = packer.pack(*value1, *value2)
struct.error: argument for 's' must be a bytes object
```

If I try like this:

```
    value2      = [idx]
```

I don't know how to do this correctly.

Comment: Why is the packing necessary? I think what you need is serialization, not packing. have a look at JSON.dumps()

Comment: You don't need the `*`; it's just `packer.pack(value1, value2)`.

Comment: @chepner also the `struct.error: argument for 's' must be a bytes object
` error

Comment: Yeah, that's why I posted an answer instead of voting to close as "could no longer be reproduced".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem is that you are unnecessarily trying to (sequence-)unpack your arguments. The `Struct` format expects a `bytes` and an `int`, and you (almost) already have them.

The second problem is that `"<"` is a *Unicode* string, and `pack` expects bytes instead. You need to properly encode the string first.

```
packed_data = packer.pack(value1.encode('utf-8'), value2)
```

The particular encoding you use doesn't matter, as long as you use the same one to unpack the data.

Note that if you *did* have a Unicode character that couldn't be encoded in one byte, your string format would be wrong. The `struct` module doesn't handle variable-length strings by itself, so it would probably be simpler to just encode the `int` by itself and concatenated that with your encoded string.

```
value = 
packed_data = value1.encode('utf-8') + struct.pack("I", value2)
```